# My node v8 is not connected to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have recently update my node version to node v8 db version v3.0.4
so which version of mongo is compatible to this?

```
"mongodb": "^1.4.38",
"mongoskin": "^1.4.13",
```

These are the mongo versions mentioned in package.json, when i was using node v6 it was pretty fine but now its is not fetcing the data from db so somebody please help

Comment: Try removing the dependency and reinstalling. `yarn remove mongodb && yarn add mongodb`

Comment: still remains same :(

Comment: May need to remove your `package-json.lock` after removing packages?

Comment: @Stretch0 removed and tried but no luck ;(

Comment: have changed to `mongodb: ^2.0.55`,` mongoskin: ^2.0.3`,`morgan : ^1.6.1`, now its connecting to db but endpoints are not returning any response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to run

```
 npm install npm@latest -g

 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

to ensure you have the latest version of node and mongodb, then you delete your `package-json.lock`. After which you can `npm start` or `nodemon` to start your app.

**Edited**

```
npm cache verify
```

if you still get the error, clear npm's cache:

```
npm cache clear --force && npm install --no-shrinkwrap --update-binary
```

OR

```
npm config set package-lock false
```

After which you can try it again.

Comment: i have followed the steps you listed above but still remains the same